# Cannot connect to testnet

Tags: mist, testnets

I installed Mist and synced the blockchain. When Mist opens,it connects to the main net by default. If I try to switch to the test network, I get an error shown on the picture below. Can anyone suggest how to get over this problem?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you try to just delete the chaindata and resync? I know it's kinda "turn it off and on again" suggestion. But it usually works for me, when things get weird with testnet.

Comment: Yeah that is what I did eventually and it fixed it.